# partial trace is invariant

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an $n\times n$ hermitian matrix and m-dimensional subspace $V$ the partial trace is defined in tao's matrix book as $\sum_{i=1}^mv_i^*Av_i$, where the $v_i$ are a basis for $V$. He says it is independent of the basis chosen, and I want to show this using this hint:

"Given two orthonormal bases for V, write the elements of one basis as a linear combination of the other basis; the coefficients will then form a unitary matrix since both bases are orthonormal. Insert these expansions of the basis elements to write the partial trace in one basis in terms of the other basis, and use the definition of a unitary matrix to simplify."

Can someone please carry out the hint? I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(v_1, \dots, v_m)$ and $(w_1, \dots, w_m)$ be two orthonormal bases of an $m$-dimensional space $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ (with respect to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$) and write $w_i = \sum_{j=1}^m u_{ij} v_j$. The matrix $U = (u_{ij})_{i,j=1}^m$ is a unitary matrix and so $U^{*}U = UU^{*} = I_m$. Then

$$ \sum_{i=1}^m w_i^{*} A w_i = \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^m u_{ij} v_j \right)^{*} A \left( \sum_{k=1}^m u_{ik} v_k \right) = \sum_{i,j,k} \overline{u_{ij}} u_{ik} v_j^{*} A v_k \\
= \sum_{jk} \left( \sum_i (U^{*})_{ji} U_{ik} \right) v_j^{*} A v_k = \sum_{jk} \delta_{jk} v_j^{*} A v_k = \sum_{j=1}^m v_j^{*} A v_j. $$